# I want to remove system app

Tags: software-uninstall

Hello developers currently I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and i want to remove 2 system apps (software update and software & update) please tell me the package file name of these apps.

Comment: This is a Ubuntu user support site for Q&A. It's for other Ubuntu users, and not developers  (*developers may drop in now & again, but it's the exception & not the rule*). If you want to reach a Ubuntu developer, a bug report is the way to go https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs or use a site like Ubuntu Community Hub for attention, but both those seem invalid, as it looks like a support question to me (though it's somewhat unclear to me what you're exactly wanting).   Are you using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop? or Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server? as apps differ...

Answer (score 4):

To remove and Software & Updates (GTK+ based graphical interface that
manages the repositories that you install software from) and Software Updater (GNOME application that manages apt updates) open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt remove software-properties-gtk update-manager
```